# Kraken2 > OTU format > Phyloseq

Tags: phylogenetics, metagenome, minion, taxonomy, microbial-genomics

A collaborator has passed me over Kraken2 outputs *.report and *.kraken, from a metatranscriptomic sequencing experiment conducted on the minION.

I would like to make a tree if the data using a standard phylogenetics package such as phyloseq, however, I am having trouble making an alignment via the OTU table..

There has been a similar question on here already, but the author has resolved it and the solution is not available.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: An OTU table is here https://github.com/smdabdoub/kraken-biom, what you require is an alignment for phyloseq